# The error threshold has been exceeded. The receive location is shutting down

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2

I am doing polling using SQL adapter......For small records polling is succesful......but for large recorde i am getting following error..

The receive location "RcvSqlDataLoc" with URL "" is shutting down. Details:"The error threshold has been exceeded. The receive location is shutting down.".

Comment: You probably see some errors in the event log?

Comment: Yes this is error in event log......below this i have one warning mesg. The adapter "SQL" raised an error message. Details "HRESULT="0x80004005" Description="The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction

Comment: This error is due to large file.....Anyone knows what settings do i need to change to poll large data from the database

Comment: It is possible also that your SQL query is timing out. Possibly look at increasing the timeout on all affected SQL and BizTalk servers, or seeing if you can improve the performance of your query.

Comment: You also want to take a look at the SQL adapter best practices below.  Its not really designed for larger datasets.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507804(v=bts.10).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking your SQL server management console for deadlocks while the long running transaction is executing. If you don't need a transaction there's an option in the configuration of the port for automatically wrapping the session in a transaction. You might try turning that off.